# How to implement sequence in the SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query in SQL Server which gives me the count of policies according to AGE and SEX as mentioned below.

```
SELECT 
    PLYMMRAGE as AGE,
    MMRSEX as SEX,
    COUNT(PLYNO) AS POLICYCOUNT
FROM 
    ADMGMPLYMSR 
GROUP BY
    PLYMMRAGE, MMRSEX
ORDER BY 
    MMRSEX DESC, PLYMMRAGE
```

Output of this query is:

```
AGE   SEX    POLICYCOUNT
------------------------
2     M      10
4     M       9
5     M       6
8     M       0
1     F       4
2     F       6
4     F       0
```

But I want that even if the age is not present the row should display for all ages with policy count as 0 till age 10.

```
    AGE   SEX    POLICYCOUNT
   -------------------------
    1     M       0
    2     M      10
    3     M       0      
    4     M       9
    5     M       6
    6     M       0
    7     M       0
    8     M       0
    9     M       0
    10    M       0
    1     F       4
    2     F       6
    4     F       0
```

and so on.

How can I insert the data with zero count if the age for that row is not present? Even if using procedure is fine

Comment: any max value for age ?

Comment: Hi i think you can looks to a CTE sql server , what is your’re sql server version please ?

Comment: max value is 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` and `coalesce` together

```
with ADMGMPLYMSR( PLYMMRAGE, MMRSEX, PLYNO ) as
(
 select 2,'M',10 union all
 select 4,'M', 9 union all
 select 5,'M', 6 union all
 select 8,'M', 0 union all     
 select 1,'M', 4 union all
 select 2,'M', 6 union all
 select 4,'M', 0     
), t AS (
    SELECT 1 AS n
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n+1 FROM t WHERE n+1<=10
)
SELECT COALESCE(PLYMMRAGE,n) as AGE, COALESCE(MMRSEX,'M') as SEX, 
       COUNT(PLYNO) AS POLICYCOUNT
  FROM t 
  LEFT JOIN ADMGMPLYMSR ON PLYMMRAGE = n
 GROUP BY coalesce(PLYMMRAGE,n), MMRSEX
 ORDER BY coalesce(MMRSEX,'M') DESC, coalesce(PLYMMRAGE,n);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/KDAI28683)</kbd>

Comment: Hi Barbaros, please can you explain the starting part ''with ADMGMPLYMSR( PLYMMRAGE, MMRSEX, PLYNO ) as
(
 select 2,'M',10 union all
 select 4,'M', 9 union all
 select 5,'M', 6 union all
 select 8,'M', 0 union all     
 select 1,'M', 4 union all
 select 2,'M', 6 union all
 select 4,'M', 0     
), t AS (
    SELECT 1 AS n
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n+1 FROM t WHERE n+1<=10
)" sorry bit new to sql server. Why you have hardcoded the result ? what should i mention there instead ?

Comment: @Ashutosh there's no such certain mechanism for new row generation is sql-server like in oracle or postgres. Since we need to add such a query, which generates the values of table "t" , above.